# Cell not show properly in iphone X

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, iphone-x

can anyone help me, Cell in iphone X is not showing properly, it show upside in collection view.

but same cell and code working fine in all other devices.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   return CGSize(width: NIConstant.SCREEN_WIDTH, height: NIConstant.SCREEN_WIDTH)
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Use Safe area layout guid to resolve this problem : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

the problem resolved by adding the piece of code in viewDidLoad method

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   fullScreenCollectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
 }
```